# How do I optimize a function with modulo?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, optimization, modulo

I have the following loop that I want to optimize:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.mover');

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  var phase = Math.sin((document.body.scrollTop/1250) + (i % 5));
  items[i].style.left = items[i].basicLeft + 100 * phase + 'px';
}
```

When I console log the output of phase. `console.log(phase)` I realize that I'm getting the same 5 numbers.

For example: 
Let's say `items.length = 200`. 
These are the results for phase.

```
i = 0  phase = 0
i = 1  phase = 0.84147
i = 2  phase = 0.90929
i = 3  phase = 0.14112
i = 4  phase = -0.75680
i = 5  phase = 0
i = 6  phase = 0.84147
i = 7  phase = 0.90929
i = 8  phase = 0.14112
i = 9  phase = -0.75680
i = 10  phase = 0
i = 11  phase = 0.84147
i = 12  phase = 0.90929
i = 13  phase = 0.14112
i = 14  phase = -0.75680
```

etc.

I want to take this line

```
var phase = Math.sin(var scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop/1250; + (i % 5));
```

out of the for loop but I can't figure out **how to pass the correct phase number back to the loop.**

So I just want to calculate phase for i < 5 since it repeats after that. How do I make it correspond so that when the for loop is at i = 25, the loop gets the correct phase.(in this case it would be 0).

Comment: There's [nothing to optimise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_optimisation) in that code. Just leave it that way.

Comment: a) Use nested loops (one from 0 to 5, one over the elements with increment of 5) b) Use an array of size 5 to memoise the values

Answer (score 1):

Storing the results for the 5 values into a temporary array.

And then modulus that with 5, should give you same results.

One thing I would say, be aware of over optimising in Javascript, sometimes you might think your making things faster, but in reality is might not be.  eg. Chromes V8 engine might even detect the pattern.  JIT compilers do some clever stuff these days.

```js
var 
  items = Array(10),
  modvar = [],
  i;
  
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) modvar[i] = 
  Math.sin((document.body.scrollTop/1250) + (i % 5));

for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  var phase = modvar[i%5];
  console.log(`i = ${i}  phase = ${phase}`);
}
```